# Android doesn't close on System.exit()

Tags: java, android

I am trying to close my App when i press on the Back Button, all it does is just going back to Launcher Activity.

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    System.exit(1);
    System.exit(0);
    finish();
}
```

I tried both, System.exit(1) and System.exit(0), together and each other alone. But nothing works as intended.

EDIT:

I have changed it to

```
        linearLayout_wrapper.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    scrollView.addView(linearLayout_wrapper);
    Log.i("Main", "initialize menu layout: complete");

}

protected void onDestroy(){
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    super.onDestroy();
}

public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
}
```

And now i get an exception when i press the back button

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child

Comment: Is your LauncherActivity in a separate process?

Comment: should be the same one

Comment: You should not use `System.exit()`. Let Android manage your app as it intends to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finish() Launcher activity when rise this activity 
then you dont need write anycode onBackPresed

read this post for close app: [Is quitting an application frowned upon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon)